# Define table name with osm2pgsql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

When I load *OpenStreetMap* data to PostGIS using [osm2pgsql](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql) the resulting tables look like this:

```
+----------+--------------------+--------+---------+
| Schema   | Name               | Type   | Owner   |
|----------+--------------------+--------+---------|
| public   | planet_osm_line    | table  | user    |
| public   | planet_osm_nodes   | table  | user    |
| public   | planet_osm_point   | table  | user    |
| public   | planet_osm_polygon | table  | user    |
| public   | planet_osm_rels    | table  | user    |
| public   | planet_osm_roads   | table  | user    |
| public   | planet_osm_ways    | table  | user    |
| public   | spatial_ref_sys    | table  | user    |
+----------+--------------------+--------+---------+
```

I do not like that the table names start with `planet`. Is it possible to define how the tables should be named?

Comment: A list of options and their usage can be found from here http://www.volkerschatz.com/net/osm/osm2pgsql-usage.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `planet` part by anything you want using the command line argument `--prefix`
The following [command](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md) will create tables such as `abc_osm_line`

```
osm2pgsql.exe source.osm.pbf --prefix abc [...other parameters as needed..]
```