# How to designate unique destination table names in OSM import to PostGIS using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

I download country cuts of OSM from [GeoFabrik](https://www.geofabrik.de/).  When I import a country's PBF file into my PostGIS instance using ogr2ogr, it simply gives me a generically named set of tables (`lines`, `points`, `multipolygons`, etc).

Even if I rename the table, it does not change everything all the way down the database structure; so when I go to import a new country pbf file, it will give me:

`ERROR 1: ERROR: relation "points_wkb_geometry_geom_idx" already exists`

The `ogr2ogr` command I'm using is:

`ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='dbname' host='host' port='5432' user='username' password='password'" country-latest.osm.pbf -lco COLUMN_TYPES=other_tags=hstore --config OSM_MAX_TMPFILE_SIZE 1024`

I have also tried the following using the `-nln` argument:

`ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='dbname' host='host' port='5432' user='username' password='password'" country-latest.osm.pbf -nln "country_name_osm_date_" -lco COLUMN_TYPES=other_tags=hstore --config OSM_MAX_TMPFILE_SIZE 1024`

But this results in:

`Warning 1: Layer creation options ignored since an existing layer is being appended to.`

Additionally it gives me geometric type mismatches, and failed copy statements, which makes sense, since `-nln` I think is trying to write everything to one table, and a PBF file will yield multiple tables.

Doubtless this question has shown how bad my ogr2ogr-fu is. So, how can I designate a specific *destination* table name in the import statement to avoid future import conflicts?

Additional note: `osm2pgsql` has the ability to use `--prefix` argument as noted here: [Define table name with osm2pgsql](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244888/define-table-name-with-osm2pgsql), however, I do not have `osm2pgsql` available to me and would like to accomplish this with `ogr2ogr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default ogr2ogr converts all the layers from the datastore and OSM datastore contains five layers http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html. The -nln option can be used for renaming just one layer. It means that if you want to rename the layers you must convert them one by one.

```
ogr2ogr ... country-latest.osm.pbf points ... -nln my_point_layer
ogr2ogr ... country-latest.osm.pbf lines ... -nln my_line_layer
ogr2ogr ... country-latest.osm.pbf multilinestrings ... -nln my_multilinestring_layer
ogr2ogr ... country-latest.osm.pbf multipolygons ... -nln my_multipolygon_layer
ogr2ogr ... country-latest.osm.pbf other_relations ... -nln my_other_relations_layer
```

Comment: tested it, success!  looks like this could be easily scripted.  thanks!